# При выводе постов рубрики при помощи цикла не работают произвольные поля

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я вывожу записи определённой рубрики на странице при помощи цикла(код ниже), и после этого перестают работать кастомные поля(плагин Advanced Custom Fields). Причём не работают только те, что расположены "ниже" в html коде странице. Я попробовал убрать цикл и всё заработало. С чем это может быть связано? Надеюсь всё понятно, жду ответов

````
                
                <?php 

                $posts = get_posts( array(
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'category_name'    => 'equipment',
                    'orderby'     => 'date',
                    'order'       => 'DESC',
                    'suppress_filters' => false, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
                ) );

                foreach( $posts as $post ){    <--сам цикл
                    setup_postdata($post);
                ?>
                
                <div class="equip-item">
                    <img src="<?php the_field('device-pict'); ?>" alt="" class="equip-img">
                    <h6 class="equip-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
                </div>

                <?php  
                }
                ?>          
            </div>
           <section class="advantages">
              <div class="container">
            
                 <h2 class="title-left"><?php the_field('advantages-title') ?></h2> <-- это и последующие поля уже не работают```
````

Answer (score 1):

Естественно. Когда выполнение попадает в ваш шаблон, отрывок из которого вы привели в вопросе,  главным циклом WordPress установлена глобальная переменная  $post. Внутри своего цикла вы изменяете значение этой глобальной переменной.

the_field() по умолчанию использует глобальную переменную $post, поэтому после вашего цикла, она пытается вывести кастомное поле последнего поста в цикле, а там его нет.

В документации по the_field() написано, что ей можно передавать второй параметр - id поста.

Всё, что вам надо сделать - запомнить текущий id до цикла

```
    $current_id = get_the_ID();
```

И использовать его после цикла

```
    the_field( 'advantages-title', $current_id )
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Хоть дело было не совсем в том чём вы сказали, это подтолкнуло меня на правильную мысль

Comment: И в чём же было дело?

Comment: У меня это происходило не в конкретных постах, а на одной странице. У меня на одной странице было несколько таких циклов и я просто в каждом переменным $post и $posts добавил номер, получилось $post1, $posts2 и тп

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.