# Проблема с WP и ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Столкнулся с проблемой при выводе произвольных полей. Использую плагин advanced Custom Fields.
the_field не выводит данные после того как  выводил данные с использованием кастомных типов постов

```
        <?php foreach(getFirstslider() as $post): ?>
    <div class="sl__first--slide">
      <div class="sl__first--wrapper">
        <div class="sl__first--left">
          <div class="sl__first--title">
            <span><?php the_field('first_slidertitle'); ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="sl__first--text">
            <span><?php the_field('first_slidertext'); ?></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sl__first--right">
          <div class="sl__first--img">
            <img src="<?php the_field('first_sliderimg'); ?>" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

после этого кода не выводин ничего!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1179821/220220

Comment: А что возвращает функция getFirstslider()? Включите WP_DEBUG, посмотрите о чем говорит ошибка

Comment: Я зарегистрировал два новых типа записей
Headerlist()
Firstslider()
вызываю их функциями
getHeaderlist()
getFirstslider()

Comment: Частично решил проблему,я думаю что она кроется в переменной $post.
Для первого цыкла я изменил имя на $post1, на $post2 во втором цыкле. 
Теперь the_field() ничего не выводит

Comment: Сейчас в масиве нет значений для the_field, как его получить?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_field('first_sliderimg', $post->ID); ?>
```

Такой вид записи нужен для вывода